# A lemma by Foguel and Weiss [1973]

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

so I am reading Krengel's text on Ergodic theorems.

And the next lemma bugs me as for the proof of it.

It's by Foguel and Weiss.

Statement:

If $P_1, P_2$ are commuting elements of a Banach algebra with $||P_1||=||P_2|| = 1$, and $Q= \alpha P_1 + (1-\alpha)P_2$ $(0<\alpha < 1)$, then: $||Q^n (P_1-P_2)|| \leq K\alpha (1-\alpha) n^{-0.5}$ for some constant $K$.

I thought that induction will do, but the basis of induction doesn't follow, I mean induction on $n$.

Answer (score 2):

First we prove the theorem for the case when $\alpha=1/2$ and $\beta=1/2$. In this case, we have $$Q^n (P_1-P_2)=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}P_1^kP_2^{n-k}(P_1-P_2)\\=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=1}^n[\binom{n}{k-1}-\binom{n}{k}]P_1^kP_2^{n-k-1}+\frac{1}{2^n}P_1^{n+1}-\frac{1}{2^n}P_2^{n+1}$$ thus we have that $$||Q^n (P_1-P_2)|| \leq \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}+\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=1}^n|\binom{n}{k-1}-\binom{n}{k}|.$$

We assume that $n$ is even. For $n$ odd it is similar. Since $\binom{n}{k}$ increases as $k$ increases from $0$ to $n/2$ and then decreases as $k$ goes from $n/2$ to $n$ the sum of absolute values is bounded by $(2/2^n)\binom{n}{n/2}$ which is, by Stirling's formula, bounded by $K/4\sqrt{N}$ for some $K$.

For the general case, the equality seems not be true. For example, let the Banach algebra to be the space of bounded linear operators of a Hilbert space $\mathcal H$, and $P_1$ be $P_2$ be two projection to two closed subspaces with intersection $\{0\}$. For the case $n=1$, we see that $$Q(P_1-P_2)=\alpha P_1- (1-\alpha)P_2$$ and the norm of it is $\sqrt{1-2\alpha+\alpha^2}$ which can not be bounded by a constant multiplied by $\alpha(1-\alpha)$.

Comment: In your last inequality, why is that: $$K\alpha/(2\sqrt{n}) \leq K\alpha (1-\alpha)/\sqrt{n}$$? I mean $1-\alpha <0.5$.

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist Sorry, in fact I think I have already made a mistake in the inequality $||Q^n (P_1-P_2)|| \leq 2K\alpha/4\sqrt{N}$ which seems that it should be $||Q^n (P_1-P_2)|| \leq 2K/(4\alpha)\sqrt{N}$. I have read the proof by Foguel and Weiss once, and I wrote down above answer from my memories, and I will check it to see how can revise the answer.

Comment: even better you can tell me which paper the result can be found.

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist I have just searched and found the paper, its name is "ON CONVEX POWER SERIES OF A CONSERVATIVE MARKOV OPERATOR", in PROCEEDINGS OF THE AMERICAN MATHEMATICAL SOCIETY, Volume 38, Number 2, April 1973. I have seen the proof, it is mostly the same as above. Maybe we can check it and find out the answer.

Comment: I'll give a look at it tomorrow and let you know what I gather. But for the meantime your last inequality doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist Yes, the last two inequalities are not right, the bigger problem is the first one. And back to the case when $n=1$ of problem I find it seems impossible to find such a constant $K$. I will check it with the paper later to make sure since I often make mistakes.

Comment: So I read the article, they only proved there for the case $\alpha =0.5$, by taking the Stirling approximation formula, and that constant multiplying $n^{-0.5}$ we can take another constant that will be multiplied by 0.25, and that will prove for that case (they don't state if the constant K depends on $\alpha$ or not).

Comment: Yes, to deduce the other case, the authors used the reduction as above, but my inequality is not right so I do not know how it works. I do not think the authors wanted $K$ depends on $\alpha$ but it seems we can not find a universal constant even when $n=1$.

Comment: I am telling you, ergodic theory is inconsistent... I shall prove it in the future... :-)

Comment: I think for $n=1$ the equality may not be true. If you would like to check it, thank you for your opinion.

Comment: And I do not quite get what you do mean by "ergodic theory is inconsistent".

Comment: Too much handwaving proofs, which makes me feel that the theory is inconsistent.

Comment: are you still there? Is there indeed something missing in proof of Foguel and Weiss?